# Reusing adapter to inflate view outside a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I'm using a BaseAdapter to inflate a listview, each item on the list is quite complex, it has several images and text, so the adapter has a lot of code. What I'm trying to achieve is when the user presses an item on the list, a new activity is launched with detailed info about the selected item, but also I want to draw the item as a summary, so I was wondering if there is a way to inflate the view using the code I already have intead of just duplicate it, I thought of something like this:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this, arrayInfo);
final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
        .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
adapter.getView(position, null, viewGroup);
```

But it doesn't work, I don't even know if what I'm trying to do makes sense or if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking about "drawing a summary"

Comment: get view from your list,list.getChildAt(position)

Comment: @LittleChild as drawing a summary i mean drawing the item itself as a summary so the user knows where they clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is another way to do it

Option #1: Move the inflate-and-widget-populate logic into a `static` method somewhere, used by both your adapter and this other bit of code.

Option #2: Create a custom `ViewGroup` that handles the inflation (and perhaps some aspects of the widget population), then use that `ViewGroup` from your adapter and wherever else it is needed.

Option #3: Create some other utility class that is responsible for inflating this layout and populating these widgets, then use that utility class from your adapter and other spots.

There are probably other options. I would not attempt to use the `Adapter` directly except in conjunction with an `AdapterView`, and particularly if the `Adapter` does not have a real model collection to adapt.

Comment: I went for the 3rd option and it worked like a charm, it's also good to know I shouldn't use the Adapter directly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to achieve is when the user presses an item on the
>   list, a new activity is launched with detailed info about the selected
>   item

Make an `Intent` to launch the new `Activity` and in the `Intent` put the data for the list item whose details are to be displayed bu using the `putExtra()` methods. In the launched `Activity`, use the `getIntent()` to retrieve this `Intent` object and then get the data from it.